# Entity Framework 4.0 - Returning List of Model objects + Count of Children Per Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm running into a common need in my project to return collections of my model objects, plus a count of certain types of children within each, but I don't know if it is possible or how to model a "TotalCount" property in a Model class and populate it as part of on single Entity Framework query, preferably using LINQ queries. Is it possible to do this whilst being able to use the Entity Framework .Include("Object") and .Skip() and .Take()? I'm new to the Entity Framework so I may be missing tons of obvious stuff that can allow this...

I would like to be able to paginate on the dynamically constructed count properties as well. I'm thinking that the most scalable approach would be to store the counts as separate database properties and then simply query the count properties. But for cases where there are small row counts that I'm dealing with, I'd rather do the counts dynamically.

In a model like this:

Table: Class

Table: Professor

Table: Attendee

Table: ClassComment

I'd like to return a list of Class objects in the form of List, but I would also like the counts of Attendees and Class comments to be determined in a single query (LINQ preferred) and set in two Class properties called AttendeeCount and ClassCommentCount.

I have this thus far:

```
var query = from u in context.Classes
            orderby tl.Name
            select u;

List<Class> topics = ((ObjectQuery<Class>)query)
    .Include("ClassComments")
    .Skip(startRecord).Take(recordsToReturn).ToList();
```

Any suggestions or alternative query approaches that can still allow the use of .Include() and pagination would be much much appreciated, in order to produce a single database query, if at all possible. Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class ClassViewModel {
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public int AttendeeCount { get; set; }
    public int ClassCommentCount { get; set; }
}


var viewModel = context.Classes.Select(clas => 
    new ClassViewModel { 
        Class = clas, 
        AttendeeCount = clas.ClassAttendes.Count, 
        ClassCommentCount = clas.ClassComments.Count}
).OrderBy(model => model.ClassCommentCount).Skip(startRecord).Take(recordsToReturn).ToList();
```

You don't have to include comments to get count.

Comment: Thanks LukLed, your suggestion is similar to Ladislav's. I will try this type of approach. But one thing that I'm still unsure of is, is it possible to order the records projected onto the anonymous type by the count properties, before applying the pagination?

Answer (score 2):

It will not work this way. The easiest approach is to use projection into anonymous (or custom) non entity type. I would try something like this:

```
var query = context.Classes
              .Include("ClassComments")  // Only add this if you want eager loading of all realted comments
              .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
              .Skip(startRecord)
              .Take(recordsToReturn)
              .Select(c => new 
                 {
                   Class = c,
                   AttendeeCount = c.Attendees.Count(),
                   ClassCommentCount = c.ClassComments.Count() // Not needed because you are loading all Class comments so you can call Count on loaded collection
                 });
```

The problem in your requirement are AttendeeCount and ClassCommentCount properties. You can't easily add them to your model because there is no corresponding column in database (unless you  define one and in such case you don't need to manually count records). You can define them in partial Class implementation but in such case you can't use them in Linq-to-entities query.

The only way to map this in EF is to use DB view and create special read only entity to represent it in your applicaiton or to use [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982038.aspx) which is custom SQL command defined in SSDL instead of DB table or view.

Comment: I seem to have been stuck to the notion of having to return my raw Entity class instances, but I'll give this approach a whirl. If I am to implement EF pagination based on these count properties, do the properties have to be database columns or database view? Thanks

Comment: @Shan: I'm not sure what you are asking for. You don't need to persistenlty store count to be able to paginate. Pagination is driven by Skip and Take and it is your responsibility to pass correct values to it. Count is usually only used to create some Pager in UI and show how many items really is in DB.

Comment: I understand that persistently storing total counts is not a pre-requisite to implementing pagination, I just wasn't sure if it was feasible to implement pagination on a LINQ to entity framework projection with dynamic count values, although LukLed indicated that it is (I am pretty new to EF).

Comment: On the topic of persisting counts in the database versus dynamically determining, I am not sure if there is ever a critical mass situation that might benefit from having total counts stored in the database, in order to avoid full table scans for each and every pagination request...i.e. what if you have millions of rows, and several types of user agents such as web, iPhone, Android, etc., all requesting the same data...I guess that's a separate design concern that I'll need to research, but that was the though behind persisting counts for paging purposes.