# How to query with Linq to Entities with a group by and two counts

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need help with a query. I want to return a list of entities and for each entities, I need two counts.

With entities generated from thoses tables :

```
    /****** Objet :  Table [dbo].[Messages]    Date de génération du script : 03/12/2013 15:31:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Messages]
Go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Messages](
    [MessageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserCreation] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DateCreation] [datetime] NOT NULL  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [UserModif] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DateModif] [datetime] NOT NULL  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [Timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Notification] [bit] NOT NULL  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [BounceTraite] [bit] NOT NULL  DEFAULT ((0)),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Messages] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Objet :  Table [dbo].[MessageLocalisations]    Date de génération du script : 03/12/2013 15:31:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MessageLocalisations]
Go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageLocalisations](
    [MessageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CodeLocalisation] [char](5) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [From] [nvarchar](100) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Message] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [TargetedAudience] [nvarchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MessageLocalisations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageID] ASC,
    [CodeLocalisation] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
/****** Objet :  Table [dbo].[MessageRecipients]    Date de génération du script : 03/12/2013 15:31:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
DROP TABLE [dbo].[MessageRecipients]
Go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageRecipients](
    [MessageID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Recipient] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [DateRead] [datetime] NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](60) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [Bounce] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreation] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateModif] [datetime] NOT NULL ,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MessageRecipients] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageID] ASC,
    [Recipient] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

In my example, my entities are messages. I need a count of recipients and a count of recipient who has read the message :

```
    (From msg In context.Messages.Include("MessageLocalisations")
                         Let countRecipients = msg.MessageRecipients.Count
                         Let countRecipientsRead = msg.MessageRecipients.Where(Function(x) x.DateRead.HasValue).Count
                         Where (msg.UserCreation.Equals(user, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                         Group By msg.MessageID Into Group
                         Select msg, Group).ToList()
```

My example doesn't work. My select statement is in error, he doesn't recognize msg. In LINQ, I'm not sure how Group works and how select work when I use Group By.

The results I'd like to have is a list of Messages which include MessageLocalisations, a count of recipients for each message, a count of recipients who has read each message.

Thanks for your help! In SQL this is so simple... :(

Comment: Can you post your table definitions (Create Table Statements)?

Comment: Where are you even using those `let` statements anywhere in the rest of the query?

Comment: I want to use them in the result so I can display the count in the UI. There's chance that I do not need them. I'm totally n00b with Linq to Entities.

Comment: Create tables statements added. I had to modify them a bit before posting but I think they'll work fine.

Comment: This link helped me. Maybe my question was a duplicate : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984337/entity-framework-4-0-returning-list-of-model-objects-count-of-children-per-o][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4984337/entity-framework-4-0-returning-list-of-model-objects-count-of-children-per-o

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query that finally solve my question :

```
context.MessageSecuriseJeu.Include("MessageSecuriseLocalisations").
                            Where(Function(w) w.UtilisateurCreation.Equals(codeUtilisateurExpediteur, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).
                            Select(Function(msg) New With {.msg = msg, .nbrDest = msg.MessageSecuriseDestinataires.Count, .nbrLu = msg.MessageSecuriseDestinataires.Where(Function(w) w.DateLecture.HasValue).Count}).tolist()
```